# Looking for a simple combinatorics approach to solve a bin-sorting question

Tags: combinatorics

I thought stars and bars but it will not work for distinct objects:

> How many ways to split $4$ identical red balls, $5$ identical green balls and $7$ identical white balls among two bins?

I was only able to do this with the solutions: consider the balls that go into one bin. Automatically, the other balls go into the second bin.Eg, the red balls can have $0,1,2,3$ or $4$ in the first bin. Etc. for the other balls.

I'm asking for a mother method because I wouldn't have thought of this myself, and want to prepare myself if I see similar question in the future. In particular, it would be very complicated with 3 or more bins.

I also tried considering something like $2^{16}$ where each object had two choices: bin one or bin two. This is obviously quite naive as well, but is there a way to "save" this method?

Look forward to reading any suggestions

Comment: Are the bins distinct? I just want to clarify it because you mentioned bin one and bin two.

Comment: As the balls of each color are identical, you should apply stars and bars for each of them and multiply for total number of arrangements.

Comment: The bins seem to be indentical. I'm not sure. The question just states "two bins"

Comment: @MathLover that sounds interesting ill give it a go. I think that's what I was attempting to do anyway

Comment: @user71207 but default, we assume urns are distinct. Your working or what I have mentioned would give solutions for urns being distinct. If urns are identical then it is a a tad bit more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

One roundabout way to salvage your approach is to decompose $2^{16}$ by color (red/green/white):
$$
2^{16} = 2^42^52^7
$$
then write the per-color count as the sum of binomial coefficients. For example, for the red balls we write $2^4$ as
$$
2^4 = {4\choose0}+{4\choose1}+{4\choose2}+{4\choose3}+{4\choose4}
$$
representing the ways to pick $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ reds to go into the first bin. But we realize the balls are indistinguishable, i.e., for each $k$, these $4\choose k$ ways are really just one way. So replace each binomial coefficient by $1$: there are therefore five ways to assign red balls to the first bin. The final result is then
$$
5\cdot 6 \cdot 8
$$

Answer (score 0):

If the bins are identical, you can make them distinct by calling one of them "the urn with more green balls. Then there are $(0|5) , (1|4) , (2|3)$ 3 ways to split the green balls, then you can do stars and bars on the remaining colors yielding $3\cdot5\cdot8$ ways to split the balls.

Importantly, this doesn't work with the red balls because there is an even number of them, and in the case where the same number of balls go into each bin, they remain indistinguishable.